# How to change background color in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts to plot stacked bar graph. But I am not able to change default background color of bar chart.

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacked-bar-charts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Tried to add background color property to chart data set but its not working.

updated:
working demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacked-bar-charts-x4c3uf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, there is an option to do that by the `colors` property.
Just pass an array of colors objects ([refer here to see the object](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/development/projects/ng2-charts/src/lib/color.ts))

[here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacked-bar-charts-xdxlnv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Add the input in the HTML like that:

```
<div style="display: block;">
   <canvas baseChart 
      [datasets]="barChartData"
      [labels]="barChartLabels"
      [options]="barChartOptions"
      [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
      [legend]="barChartLegend"
      [chartType]="barChartType"
      [colors]="colors">//<---------------the colors input property
   </canvas>
</div>
```

Then just add in your ts file the next object:

```
  public colors = [
    { backgroundColor:"red" },
    { backgroundColor:"green" },
    { backgroundColor:"blue" },
    { backgroundColor:"yellow" }
  ];
```